# Access JSON array in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following JSON data:

[image]

I'm wanting to loop over the 'searchable' array for every element returned in my blade.php. I've tried so many things but just can't seem to get it to work.

My Controller code:

```
    $searchResults = (new Search())
        ->registerModel(Article::class, 'title')
        ->search('hello');

    return view('article.articles')->with('searchResult', json_decode($searchResults, true));
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the id:

```
//blade.php

@foreach($searchResult as $element)

    {{$element['searchable']['id']}} //Retrieve the id

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried:

        foreach ($searchResult as $element)
            foreach ($element['searchable'] as $searchableArray)
                <p>{{ $searchableArray }}</p>
            endforeach
        endforeach

And the output is:


27

28

hello

<p>grfgegherh</p>

2020-12-24T20:02:11.000000Z

2020-12-24T20:02:11.000000Z

28

28

hello123

<p>rttttttt</p>

2020-12-24T21:58:26.000000Z

2020-12-24T21:58:26.000000Z

However, I want to access each element, such as ID, title, by itself, is this possible?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the id you can do this: <p>{{$searchableArray['id']}}</p>. Just replace the key depending on what you want to retrieve.

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't quite work as I'm getting a "trying to access array offset on value of type int" error when I try what you suggested.

Comment: I was a little too hasty. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)